# Error when using Ui-bootstrap pagination with $http.get for api data

Tags: angularjs, api, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-promise

I have pagination working [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/AD1AGCYIm1dZhbuoPhxX?p=preview)

But I want to change the data to use the API data I am creating however i am getting an error and I'm not sure why.

This is the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

This is the code:

```
angular.module('cbuiRouterApp')
  .controller('BrowseCtrl', function ($scope, $http, socket) {
    $scope.itemData = [];
    $http.get('/api/items').success(function(itemData) {
      $scope.itemData = recipeData;
      socket.syncUpdates('Item', $scope.itemData);
    });


    $scope.predicate = '-created_at';

    $scope.totalItems = $scope.itemData.length;
    $scope.itemsPerPage = 21
    $scope.currentPage = 1;
    $scope.maxSize = 5;

    $scope.pageCount = function () {
      return Math.ceil($scope.itemData.length / $scope.itemsPerPage);
    };

    $scope.itemData.$promise.then(function () {
      $scope.totalItems = $scope.itemData.length;
      $scope.$watch('currentPage + itemsPerPage', function() {
        var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.itemsPerPage),
          end = begin + $scope.itemsPerPage;

        $scope.filteredItems = $scope.itemData.slice(begin, end);
      });
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$http.get('/api/items')` returns a promise but itemData does not have a promise so you can't call `$promise.then` on it. If you want that code to run after itemData loads why don't you just put it in the `success` callback. e.g.:

```
angular.module('cbuiRouterApp')
  .controller('BrowseCtrl', function ($scope, $http, socket) {
    $scope.itemData = [];
    $http.get('/api/items').success(function(itemData) {
      $scope.itemData = recipeData;
      socket.syncUpdates('Item', $scope.itemData);

      //Moved to here
      $scope.totalItems = $scope.itemData.length;
      $scope.$watch('currentPage + itemsPerPage', function() {
        var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.itemsPerPage),
          end = begin + $scope.itemsPerPage;

        $scope.filteredItems = $scope.itemData.slice(begin, end);
      });

    });


    $scope.predicate = '-created_at';

    $scope.totalItems = $scope.itemData.length;
    $scope.itemsPerPage = 21
    $scope.currentPage = 1;
    $scope.maxSize = 5;

    $scope.pageCount = function () {
      return Math.ceil($scope.itemData.length / $scope.itemsPerPage);
    };
  });
```

Comment: Bang on the mark mate! That was exactly what the problem was, thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

What is `recipeData`?
At first you set `$scope.itemData = [];`, then after $http returns a value, you set       `$scope.itemData = recipeData;`, which is undefined.

Surely, nor Array, nor undefined don't have `$promise` property.

Basically you're trying to do `[].$promise.then()` because you're doing it before $http is finished.

Not sure what you're trying to achieve..

Maybe something like

```
$http.get('/api/items').$promise.then(function (itemData) {
    $scope.itemData = itemData;
    socket.syncUpdates('Item', $scope.itemData);
    $scope.totalItems = $scope.itemData.length;
    $scope.$watchCollection('[currentPage, itemsPerPage]', function() {
        var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.itemsPerPage),
            end = begin + $scope.itemsPerPage;

        $scope.filteredItems = $scope.itemData.slice(begin, end);
    });
});
```

?